# How can i print the value of let symbol in rspec?

Tags: rspec, automation, capybara

if i have following lines in my spec

```
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  let(:competition_date) { Date.today+10.days }
```

How can i print the value of competition_date symbol in rspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RSpec, the variables defined in `let` are accessible in `before` and `it` blocks. All must be enclosed within a `describe` block, however, as in:

```
describe "let variables" do
  let(:competition_date) { Date.today+10.days }
  it "should be accessible within it blocks" do
    expect(competition_date).to be == Date.today+10.days
    puts competition_date
  end
end
```